# How do I reset the WLAN "network security key" for my router?

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I have a T-Sinus 154 DSL Router.

I can connect machines to the Internet with it fine via network cable.

But I want use WLAN but the WLAN was set up a long time ago but when I try to connect to it, **I am asked for the "Network Security Key"** which I don't have so I would like to change the Network Security Key for WLAN for this router.

I access the router via Internet Explorer **192.168.2.1**, type in my **password** and go to Network Settings, Wireless, there I can set up:

- Wireless on/off
- Canal and SSI (which I called **WLAN3**)
- transfer speed
- base speed
- canal

But there is **no place** to type in the "Network Security Key".

When I search Google for "T-Sinus 154 DSL network security key" I can find nothing useful (even in German).

**What am I missing about defining a Network Security Key for this router? Why isn't it on the same screen as where you set everything else up for the WLAN connection? Why is there nothing about the network security key in the documentation or the router settings menu?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many variations of this router.

Have a look here: [(T-)Sinus 154 Serie](http://hilfe.telekom.de/hsp/cms/content/HSP/de/3378/theme-45859527/theme-45858841/theme-45858824/theme-45858808%3Bjsessionid%3DA4DB81B013C2CE9D2C301DB535ECC320&rurl=translate.google.ca&twu=1&usg=ALkJrhipCY_ocaJCTrulvBBy-r3TJzZclw)

This might be of help too: [T-Sinus 154 Install PDF](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=6&ved=0CCAQFjAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.t-home.de%2Fdlp%2Feki%2Fdownloads%2Fs%2FSinus154stick_kba_e_14.01.05-.pdf&rct=j&q=T-Sinus+154+DSL+%2B+configuration+screens&ei=S7sGS-ycLNGSlAekvfWEBA&usg=AFQjCNGJ168Pn-8B0TGz_yXSDwGyiuDZuA)

You may want to also look into [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/)